# Renaming files across several subfolders based on a list of new names

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rename a bunch of files across several subfolders of "Folder." I have compiled a list of the new names in excel.  Running a trial on two subfolders containing 22 and 26 files.  It works fine for the first 22 files in subfolder 1, but instead of moving to subfolder 2 at that point, it starts renaming files in subfolder 1 a second time.  Any thoughts?

```
Sub change_File_Names()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFolders As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim oSubFolder As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolders = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Folder").SubFolders

For Each oFolder In oFolders
    
    Set oSubFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(oFolder.Path)
        
    For Each oFile In oSubFolder.Files
        oFile.Name = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next oFile
    
Next oFolder
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Code works as intended in my testing. Are your folders structured as "C:\Folder\Subfolder1" and "C:\Folder\Subfolder2"? Or are they like "C:\Folder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2"?

Comment: Cycling through all folders and subfolders is a common topic. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-59.html

Comment: @kevin The former.  Bizarre.  Realized I didn't need the oSubFolder line since oFolder is the subfolder, so deleted that.  I double checked that the collection of Files is correct size (22 & 26), but it's continuing to rename files in Subfolder 1 42 times before moving on to subfolder 2, where it names 6, then gives me an error (because there are no more file names).

Comment: What collection are you checking to see 22 & 26 files? It shouldn't matter how many files are in the folders since you're doing `For Each`, there is no correct or incorrect size. Add some debugging: before the `For Each` loop add `MsgBox oFolders.Count` - the message box should say 2. Immediately after `For Each oFolder In oFolders` add `MsgBox oFolder.Name` - 1 message box should show the first folder, then a 2nd message box should show the second folder. Do those show the right numbers & folder names?

Comment: @kevin ha I was laughing when I saw this because it was almost verbatim what I added to debug.  When I add these, the msgbox's appear how I would expect (2, subFolder1, subFolder 2) and I also added msgbox's to report the file count in each subfolder and those were correct.  I'm at a loss.  Might just do one subfolder at a time at this point.